# What sequence do these numbers form (possibly related to Bernoulli numbers)?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have computed the following terms in a sequence:

$\left\{1,-\frac{\pi ^2}{72},\frac{\pi ^4}{21600},-\frac{\pi ^6}{1270080},\frac{\pi
   ^8}{36288000},-\frac{\pi ^{10}}{632282112},\dots\right\}$

I am trying to guess what sequence they form. I suspect it has to do with Bernoulli numbers, as when I divide by the sequence

$-(-1)^nB_{2n-2}(2n)!^{-1}\pi^{2n-2}$

for $n=1,2,\dots$

then I get the simpler sequence

$\left\{2,2,-1,\frac{4}{3},-3,10\right\}$

But I still cannot guess the full sequence... I have tried looking on online lists of sequences with no luck.

Comment: Have you put the denominators into OEIS?

Comment: yes, this was the first thing i tried, sadly no luck

Comment: Did you notice that all denominators are multiples of $72$ ? Probably of no use.

Comment: Could you tell in which context did you get these numbers ?

Comment: Please give a few more terms. I have a possible sequence but want to make sure it agrees with your values.

Comment: its very difficult to compute each term (it took more about a week on a computer cluster to get the last term), so it you have an ansatz, please say!

Comment: the context is that I am computing the quantum corrections of the density matrix of a quantum mechanics system with Hamiltonian $H=\cosh(2\pi p)+(N-2) \cosh(2\pi q)+\cosh(2\pi (q+m/2))+ \cosh(2\pi(q-m/2))$ in a small $m$ expansion using the Wigner formalism, where $\hbar=1/(2\pi)$. In practice, the corrections come from expanding a Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff and Moyal bracket to high order, which gets computationally expensive very quickly. the quartic in $m$ expansion could be resummed in terms of Bernoulli numbers, I'm hoping that the quadratic in $m$, which is this series, can be resummed too

Comment: Note $(2,2,-1,4/3,-3,10)*(0,1,2,3,4,5)/2 = (0,1,-,1,2,-6,25)$ but that is hard to guess.

Comment: do you have a guess for the general sequence?

what might be useful: quartic in $m$ term is the sequence 

$\left\{\frac{\pi ^2}{12},\frac{\pi ^4}{720},-\frac{\pi ^6}{60480},\frac{\pi
   ^8}{1814400},-\frac{\pi ^{10}}{31933440},\frac{691 \pi
   ^{12}}{261534873600},\dots\right\}$, 

which I was able to guess takes the form $-\pi^2 n(2n-1)(-1)^nB_{2n}B_{2n-2}(2n)!^{-1}\pi^{2n-2}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$. this is partly why i expect Bernoulli numbers to show up for our sequence... but  I could be wrong